# цикл исходя из родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как пройтись по циклу исходя из родителя.

```js
$( ".root > div > div" ).click(function() {
  var thissku = $(this);
  //alert(thissku.attr('name'));
  $(thissku.parent()).each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
  <div class="div-root">
    <div name="1">test</div>
    <div name="2">test</div>
    <div name="2">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

почему у меня `.parent()` не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во первых не стоит заворачивать ещё раз в jq $(thissku.parent()) делайте так thissku.parent()

во вторых - вы приходитесь циклом по родителю, а он один. Берите его детей

```
  thissku.parent().children('div').each(function(index, el) {
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.